# Getting a tree node using the name and not the position

Tags: xhtml, primefaces

How to get a child tree node using the name and not the range of the node in the child node list .

i found this method but it uses the position of the element in the children list:

```
selectedNode.getChildren().get(i).
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection you receive by calling `getChildren()` is a standard Java collection IIRC and is not indexed by name. The only ways I can think of realizing this is to create your own Node implementation or to iterate over the collection (which I think is the easiest solution).

```
public Node getNodeByName(String name)
{
    for (Node n : selectedNode.getChildren())
    {
        if (name.equals(n.getName())
        { return n; }
    }
    return null;
}
```